# DSA Signature Verification and BigInteger class

Tags: java, encryption, biginteger, dsa, pari

I have been given a (very) simple DSA problem, and have already found the key and other variables. To verify the signature I need to somehow translate the equation:

V = [(**y^u1*h^u2**)mod p] mod q

into a BigInteger operation. Is this even possible on java? I have been using modPow successfully so far however all problems so far have been in the form:

r.modPow(exponent, modulus);

I have no idea how to do the above equation (in particular the bold part) via BigInteger and I'm wondering if it's even possible. Does anyone have any ideas?

How would I go about putting this equation through Pari if BigInteger can't do it?

Comment: To answer how you can do it in PARI/GP, you can just do `V = ((y^u1*h^u2) % p) % q`. This will not use the optimization described by the answer below, however. To do that (necessary only if the intermediate values are huge, but almost always faster, I guess), try `V = lift(Mod(y,p)^u1*Mod(h,p)^u2) % q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to use the identity that

```
(a*b) mod p == ((a mod p)*(b mod p)) mod p
```

So to calculate y<sup>u1</sup> × h<sup>u2</sup> mod p:

1. calculate y<sup>u1</sup> mod p, using `modPow`,
2. calculate h<sup>u2</sup> mod p, using `modPow`,
3. multiply together the results of steps 1 and 2,
4. reduce the result of step 3 mod p.

Step 4 is necessary because the results of steps 1 and 2 may multiply together to produce a value greater than p.